# how to write firebase v8 code using firebase v9

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This code block is written in Firebase v8 syntax but how to write this code using firebase v9?

[image]

Comment: Hello, what did you try?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check [the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) for the upgrade to V9, and you need update your library `react-firebase-hooks` to 4.0.0 version ([here documentation](https://github.com/csfrequency/react-firebase-hooks/tree/b33a455769df5ad66926bc8755294b2b277e3c5b/firestore#usecollection)).

In your example, it would look like this:

```js
import { useCollection } from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore'
import { getFirestore, collection, query, where } from 'firebase/firestore'

const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

const q = query(collection(db, 'chats'), where('users', 'array-contains', user.email));
const [value, loading, error] = useCollection(
  q,
  { snapshotListenOptions: { includeMetadataChanges: true } }
)
```